# Discord.js Websocket

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this problem with discord.js and when I do m.ping (m. is the prefix) it shows this

```
Pong!
```

Websocket ping is ${client.ws.ping}MS!
Message edit ping is ${msg.createdAt - message.createdAt}

here is the code

```js
await msg.edit(client.embed({
            title: `Pong!`,
            description: 'Websocket ping is ${client.ws.ping}MS!\nMessage edit ping is ${msg.createdAt - message.createdAt}'
        }, message));
        await msg.edit("");
```

So please help

Comment: Learn about Template strings [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks instead of `'` in the `description`. There might be other errors as well so it would be great if you could provide the rest of the code.

Here is the edited code using backticks:

```js
await msg.edit(client.embed({
            title: `Pong!`,
            description: `Websocket ping is ${client.ws.ping}MS!\nMessage edit ping is ${msg.createdAt - message.createdAt}`
        }, message));
await msg.edit("");
```